# Calculate max from array with some non-numeric values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to calculate the maximum value for 15-minute data I'm importing from a .csv file. Each row in the file contains the 15-min data from a different source (`"ID"`) from a different day (`"Date"`), but there are additional columns that are not needed (`"Class", "Sample", "Channel"`) for my analysis.

I looked at using `d3.group`, but it doesn't seem like having five key values (one for each of the non-numeric values) is the right way to go about it.

Importing the data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "10D1012B",
    "Class": "R",
    "Sample": "135_OLD",
    "Channel": "1",
    "Date": "1/1/2019",
    "00:15": "0.48",
    "00:30": "0.6",
    "00:45": "0.896",
    "01:00": "0.712",
    "01:15": "1.12",
          ...
    "23:00": "0.48",
    "23:15": "0.6",
    "23:30": "0.624",
    "23:45": "0.552",
    "00:00": "0.704"
  },
  {
    "ID": "10D1040B",
    "Class": "R",
    "Sample": "135_OLD",
    "Channel": "1",
    "Date": "1/2/2019",
    "00:15": "1.016",
         ...
    "23:30": "0.632",
    "23:45": "0.72",
    "00:00": "0.776"
  }
]
```

I would like to calculate the maximum value for each row of data (ID,Date pair) so I can use that to create the chart scale. It's not clear to me how to exclude the non-numeric columns when calculating the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems: first, `d3.max` traverse different *objects* in the same *array*... however, you need to traverse different *values* in the same *object*. Second, you have some numerical values, like for the `"Channel"` property, that you also don't want to include. So, the thing is not as simple as just finding all the numerical values in the properties.

That being said, here's my suggestion: set a list of property names, or keys, that you don't want to check...

```
const nonNeededKeys = ["ID", "Class", "Sample", "Channel", "Date"];
```

... and then use `d3.max` for all other keys in each object inside the array:

```
data.forEach(function(row) {
  const keys = d3.keys(row).filter(function(d) {
    return nonNeededKeys.indexOf(d) === -1;
  });
  row.maxValue = d3.max(keys.map(function(d) {
    return +row[d]
  }))
});
```

Here, as you can see, for each object, I'm creating a new property named `maxValue`.

Here is the demo:

```js
const data = [{
    "ID": "10D1012B",
    "Class": "R",
    "Sample": "135_OLD",
    "Channel": "1",
    "Date": "1/1/2019",
    "00:15": "0.48",
    "00:30": "0.6",
    "00:45": "0.896",
    "01:00": "0.712",
    "01:15": "1.12",
    "23:00": "0.48",
    "23:15": "0.6",
    "23:30": "0.624",
    "23:45": "0.552",
    "00:00": "0.704"
  },
  {
    "ID": "10D1040B",
    "Class": "R",
    "Sample": "135_OLD",
    "Channel": "1",
    "Date": "1/2/2019",
    "00:15": "1.016",
    "23:30": "0.632",
    "23:45": "0.72",
    "00:00": "0.776"
  }
];

const nonNeededKeys = ["ID", "Class", "Sample", "Channel", "Date"];

data.forEach(function(row) {
  const keys = d3.keys(row).filter(function(d) {
    return nonNeededKeys.indexOf(d) === -1;
  });
  row.maxValue = d3.max(keys.map(function(d) {
    return +row[d]
  }))
});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

After that, calculating the maximum value for **all** objects is very easy:

```
const maxValue = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.maxValue;
});
```

And the running snippet:

```js
const data = [{
    "ID": "10D1012B",
    "Class": "R",
    "Sample": "135_OLD",
    "Channel": "1",
    "Date": "1/1/2019",
    "00:15": "0.48",
    "00:30": "0.6",
    "00:45": "0.896",
    "01:00": "0.712",
    "01:15": "1.12",
    "23:00": "0.48",
    "23:15": "0.6",
    "23:30": "0.624",
    "23:45": "0.552",
    "00:00": "0.704"
  },
  {
    "ID": "10D1040B",
    "Class": "R",
    "Sample": "135_OLD",
    "Channel": "1",
    "Date": "1/2/2019",
    "00:15": "1.016",
    "23:30": "0.632",
    "23:45": "0.72",
    "00:00": "0.776"
  }
];

const nonNeededKeys = ["ID", "Class", "Sample", "Channel", "Date"];

data.forEach(function(row) {
  const keys = d3.keys(row).filter(function(d) {
    return nonNeededKeys.indexOf(d) === -1;
  });
  row.maxValue = d3.max(keys.map(function(d) {
    return +row[d]
  }))
});

const maxValue = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.maxValue
})
console.log(maxValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. My data set has data from many ID's for many dates. Would there be a benefit to using a d3.group to structure the data like here https://github.com/d3/d3-array#group. And then once the data is in the group, it's a little unclear how to chart a single ID for a single date. I realize that's beyond the scope of the original question. Happy to edit the original question or submit a new question.

Comment: Please don't edit your question: if you have a different issue, post a new question.